# compare string whether its in a date format ANDROID

Tags: android

Hi i got a data that is scan from the `QR` code with contain `DateTime` . but now i want to make a validation where , the code will proceed to another activity when its scan only date and time . I post the code here

```
 Log.i("<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>> ",
                        "<<<<Bar Code>>> " + sym.getData());
                scanResult = sym.getData().trim();


                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

                if(scanResult.equals(dateFormat))
                {
                    new createClockIn().execute();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(BarcodeScanner.this, "Sorry this is not a valid date and time",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", staffIDStr1);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
```

but this is seems to be wrong when im scan the qr code with the date and time , its pops out the toast. The data should be inserted to the database like this

[image]

Comment: What type is scanResult? String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the ScanResult-String into a Date-Object. This is done by using parse()-method of your SimpleDateFormatter. Equals does not work here!

Try to parse your ScanResult:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");    
try {
    final Date dateResult = dateFormat.parse(scanResult);
    SimpleDateFormat outFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    final String formattedForDatabase = outFormat.format(dateResult);
    // TODO Do your stuff.
    new createClockIn().execute();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Toast.makeText(BarcodeScanner.this, "Sorry this is not a valid date and time",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", staffIDStr1);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example string of the scan result?

Comment: i put the picture of my database . when qr code is scan , the data will insert to database . those data is without the validation that i want to do now

Comment: *in the question (picture)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't believe that. This should work. What is the output of your logcat. Log.i("<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>> ",
                        "<<<<Bar Code>>> " + sym.getData());

Comment: how to find in the logcat ?

Comment: Search for your tags???? "<<<<<<Asset Code"

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: 03-18 16:43:18.766  29390-29390/? I/<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>>﹕ <<<<Bar Code>>> 2016/03/18 16:42:08
03-18 16:43:20.221  29390-29390/? I/<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>>﹕ <<<<Bar Code>>> 2016/03/18 16:42:08
03-18 16:43:21.926  29390-29390/? I/<<<<<<Asset Code>>>>>﹕ <<<<Bar Code>>> 2016/03/18 16:42:08

Comment: Indeed your parsing pattern was wrong. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: ha yess , after i see the logcat now i realize my mistakes . thankyou for your answer and help .

Comment: accepting and upvoting an answer is the way to go on SO! :)

Comment: btw , do you have any idea how to separate the data ? if possible i would like to save my data in "date" , "time" . instead of dateTime

Comment: use two different formatters. One for the date and for the time part.

Answer (score 0):

Handle Exception like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
        sdf.parse(scanResult);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Invalid Date
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @ekinidris what string you are getting in scanResult?

Comment: what do you mean ? it supposed to be date and time . i put the picture in the question

Comment: @ekinidris in that case it is valid format

Comment: yes i think so too , but it still give error that it is not a valid date time format

Comment: @ekinidris don't think please debug the application and tell us what is you are getting in scanResult.